# how to inherit a List<object> from one assembly to another assembly in asp.net with designer support as inner Property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, assemblies

i have a list collection in the assembly 1. How can i get the this List Collection from another assembly 2 where as that list collection have several inner list collection.

Thanks in advance.

```
namespace Scripter.JavaScript.billng.Models
{
    public class class_1
    {
private List<MyObject> obj=null;
               [Browsable(true)]
               [NotifyParentProperty(true)]
               [Bindable(true)]
               [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
               public List<MyObject> Cost
               {
                   get { return this.obj; }
                   set { this.obj= value; }
               }
    }
}


namespace Designer.JavaScript.billng.Models
{
    public class class_2
    {
//How can i access the List<MyObject> here. More over My object has several Collection in it. i need to inherits those collection too
}

}
```

namespace Scripter.JavaScript.billng.Models is in Assembly1 and namespace Designer.JavaScript.billng.Models is in assembly2.

Comment: Please provide an example or some code. I don't understand your Problem.

Answer (score 0):

From your Designer namespace, you will need to access the Scripter namespace either by using fully qualified names or by doing a "using".

Example:

```
//Fully qualified name:
Scripter.JavaScript.billng.Models.class_1.Cost = new List<MyObject>();

// with "using"
using Scripter.JavaScript.billng.Models;
...
class_1.Cost = new List<MyObject>();
```

Comment: But i am unable to get inner collection in the List<MyObject>. how can i get it?

Comment: You will need to do the same for whatever namespace contains your MyObject object. Either put a using (recommended) on top of the Designer class file or use fully qualified names.